# std::strftime displays timezone UTC as UTC+1 using gmtime in windows

Tags: c++, timezone, window, utc, strftime

I am trying to understand why in windows (in linux works) std::strftime displays the timezone UTC as UTC+1.

If I run the next code

```
#include <ctime>
#include <chrono>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::time_t t = std::time(nullptr);
    
    char utc_str[80];
    std::strftime(utc_str, 80, "%H:%M:%S %z", std::gmtime(&t));
    std::string utcStd = { utc_str };
    std::cout << "UTC: " << utcStd << std::endl;

    char local_str[80];
    std::strftime(local_str, 80, "%H:%M:%S %z", std::localtime(&t));
    std::string localStd = { local_str };
    std::cout << "Local: " << std::string(localStd) << std::endl;

    return 0;
 }
```

I get the next output:

```
    UTC: 07:26:18 +0100
    Local: 09:26:18 +0200
```

Where the UTC and localtime times are correct but the UTC timezone is incorrect.

Any ideas?

Comment: Does it correlate to current dst offset ?

Comment: If you are referring to the [UTC/GMT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) time, no, this time is not affected by the Daylight saving time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Microsoft has been always famous for its implementations of C library functions to work somewhat differently than specified in standards. Other platform vendor doing that is Apple. As it has lasted for decades it must be is deliberate strategy.

There are [bugs reported](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/434145/strftime-wcsftime-incorrect-time-zone-offset.html) about that time zone in Visual Studio implementation of strftime. Perhaps what you observe is other "bug", other manifestation of same "bug" or new manifestation of some "fix".

Usage of some open source library can be less headache than what these library vendors provide. Typical suggestion is [boost](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_73_0/doc/html/date_time.html) but I have observed it to be inefficient and to misbehave. The [one by Howard Hinnant](https://github.com/HowardHinnant/date) is quite decent.

Comment: I would have to accept that this appears to be the most plausible option.
In the meantime I [reported this](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/1105670/stdstrftime-displays-timezone-utc-as-utc1-using-st.html) to Microsoft.